# Using REGEXMATCH to find cells with EXACT string length, not cells with shared words and different strings

Tags: string, google-sheets, filter, replace

I'm working on a sheet where I want to use REGEXMATCH to filter out cells with certain exact strings.

[Here is an example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mfns8ZKRk_eS9H-3ac-AY7n4utz4ECAi3-k7ZOdwgeo/edit?usp=sharing).

The way I have the formula now, I can only find cells with words that are shared instead of the entire string.

Could someone help me with the answer? I'm okay using a different function (not regexmatch) altogether. It'd also be nice if someone could link me a page that goes through everything about regex stuff, but for newbies.

I've tried looking at RegEx language patterns, but it's a little hard for me to grasp, and I can't seem to put in a phrase the app likes that both 1. encompasses multiple specified strings, and 2. terminate the entire search term at the end of the word, nothing else after. Also not sure of any functions that would handle this sort of thing, because FILTER didn't work, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going to use regex, you would have to force it to match the whole string between the start and end of line like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "^(rod|poker)$"), "", A2:A))
```

[image]

so it's better *not* to use regex in this case.

It's difficult to recommend a good tutorial for regex, one reason being that regex is almost always seen as part of another application - (in this case Google Sheets of course but it could just as well be JavaScript or a Unix shell) - and exists in different flavours. The gold standard is probably [Rex Egg](https://www.rexegg.com/) and then for testing and development [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) but maybe [this](https://ryanstutorials.net/regular-expressions-tutorial/regular-expressions-basics.php) gives a gentler introduction without getting bogged down in too many concepts straight away.

Comment: Marked as best. Thank you! Thank you for the links as well--figured out fast that there were several different ways to use regex depending on what you're using (so that ALSO discouraged me while looking.)

Answer (score 1):

*Here's a `non-regex` solution for sheets:*

```js
=filter(A4:A,not(countif(E4:E,A4:A)))
```

- *I've arranged the search terms `rod`, `poker` in **Column_E** (as in screenshot). you can also hardcode them inside the formula if you prefer that way*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep this advice in mind. I've marked this answer as helpful, but I'm not sure if it  will show up until I have 15 reputation? I'll look up if there's a way I can help your numbers later.